# SQL Adding unmatched Join results to output

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Maybe I am approaching the entire problem wrong - or inefficiently.

Essentially, I am trying to combine two views of data, one of them a log table, based upon 2 criteria:

1. RoomName field match
2. Timestamp matches

vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule (RoomName, StartTime, EndTime, Subject, etc)
This contains the schedule of events for all indexed rooms - times in UTC.

vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory (RoomName, OnTime, OffTime, etc)
This is a log of activity that has been paired down to just show when the room display has been turned on and off - times in UTC.

I am wanting to match display on/off activities with the events scheduled in the room when the logged activities occurred.

The query is really long, and includes a lot of derived fields.  Hopefully just focusing on the join section will make it more clear.

```
SELECT <foo>
FROM dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule
  INNER JOIN dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory
  ON dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule.RoomName =  
        dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory.RoomName
  AND dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule.EndTime >=
        dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory.OnTime
  AND dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule.StartTime <=
        dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory.OffTime
```

This query is working great.  By design, some events are listed more than once.  This happens when there are multiple on/off display cycles that occur within the window of the same event.  Similarly, if a room display is turned on before or during one event and stays on through a following event, data from that single log entry is used on both the first and second event record.  So this query is doing exactly what is needed in this aspect.

However, I also want to add back into the output, scheduled events (from the vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule view) that have no corresponding logged activities in the vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory.

I have tried various forms on UNION on another query of the vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule view with null values in the and the fields otherwise taken or derived from  vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory view.  But it adds all scheduled activities back in - not just the ones with no match from the initial join.

I can provide more details if needed.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I may just not be fully understanding, but don't you just mean you want to do a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: That did occur to me, but when I try it, I get a whole lot of additional entries that don't look valid.  For example, the RoomName field from the DisplayUsageHistory side is 'null' - and there are no null entries in the actual DisplayUsageHistory view.

Comment: But you might be right actually.  I was letting that confuse me - when that would be exactly what it would do.  I am checking into it more.

Comment: Yep, I just checked.  You are exactly right.  The problem was I was referencing the dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_DisplayUsageHistory.RoomName field rather than the dbo.vw_FusionRVDB_Schedule.RoomName field - and sorting by it.  All the extra null entries confused me and I thought it was making extra (incorrect matches).  Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: HepC, I guess I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HepC answered in the comments.  I was letting the results confuse me.  A left join did the trick.